# How can I pull from a fork, without Git detecting two equal file contents but with different names?

Tags: git, github

Let's assume the repo I have forked, has the following dir/files:

```
├── Directory A
│   └── Notebook_00.ipynb
|   └── Notebook_01.ipynb
```

I have now made some small edits to `Notebook_00.ipynb` and renamed it to `Notebook_00_Personal.ipynb` pushing a commit into my own repo.

Later on, the original owner of the fork pushed a commit modifying both `Notebook_00.ipynb` and `Notebook_01.ipynb`.

When I try to fetch & pull from the fork, Git tells me that there are some conflicts (due to my edits) between my modified `Notebook_00_Personal.ipynb` and the original `Notebook_00.ipynb` from the fork.

Basically Git still detects that the file it has to merge it's my modified one, while what I want is that Git creates "again" that `Notebook_00.ipynb` file.

Git also detects this even if I create a new whole directory inside `Directory A` and placing my personal edited Notebook, it will still merge the commit into my modified .ipynb file.

Is there any way I can prevent this from happening?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: what about don't renaming the file, keep it.

Comment: I want to have my version of the notebook, as well as the one from the official fork.

Comment: you said you rename it not you copy it, just copy it

Comment: Surprisingly, copying the file and after it just renaming it, worked. Thank you.